# How to 'NULL' a string in c++

Tags: c++, string

I am new in C++ and now I am learning how cin and cout works. The case is, as you can see in the code below I create a `string`, and a `char *` in order to compare the C way to read a string and the C++ way. In C++, it makes sense that if I create a string then I worry about to set this string to NULL?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#define SIZE 10

using namespace std;
int main () {
  cout << "Write Something: \n";
  string f1;
  char *p;
  p = (char *) malloc(SIZE); // This is how I will use it in c
  getline(cin, f1);
  cout << "Write Something else: \n";
  scanf("%s", p);
  cout << f1 << "1\t";
  printf("%s2\n", p);
  free(p);
  p = NULL; // After the pointer has been freed, we set it to NULL
  cout << "p freed\t";
  f1.clear();
  cout << "f1 deleted\t";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `std::string` can be _empty_ (i.e., `""`), or it can have one-or-more `char`. It cannot be `NULL`.

Comment: Ok, and can this memory allocated be freed without using ```free()```

Comment: Most objects in C++ manage their own resources.  I haven't needed to use `malloc` or `new` or `new[]` in about a decade.  Instead I use `std::vector`, or `std::unique_ptr`, or if I really have to `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Eljay so in c++ ```strings``` aren't like ```String``` in java, always will have a value different to NULL?

Comment: Java and C++ are very different languages, with very different primitives, and very different memory management.  Even a rather different approach to object-oriented programming.  So, yes, you are correct, C++ `std::string` is not like Java `String`.  (Likewise with JavaScript, except the OO is even more different.)

Comment: Oh, and I didn't intend to imply that any of those languages are "better" or "worse" than any other languages.  Those are all fine, mainstream, popular languages.  Languages are tools, and as such are more-or-less suitable for a given problem domain.

Comment: Re: "`// After the pointer has been freed, we set it to NULL`" -- `p` isn't used after it gets freed, so setting it to `NULL` doesn't accomplish anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to worry about setting a `std::string` object to NULL.

And you don't have to `clear()` it if it is just going to go out of scope right afterwards. Its destructor will handle freeing any memory used for the character data for you.

Comment: Ok, so in C++ the risk there was in C when we use ```malloc()``` doesn't exists?

Comment: @Josep Whatever you `malloc` - you `free`. Whatever you `new` - you `delete`. Whatever you `new[]` - you `delete[]`. If you don't do those - you don't worry them.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to even clear f1, as the RAII will automatically cleanup, when the function returns.

Comment: C++ does not have garbage collection

Comment: RAII is not at all like a garbage collector. Objects in C++ don't hang around until the garbage collector gets around to releasing them. They get destroyed when they go out of scope. There are many advantages to that.